# append to list in r based on element in vector

Tags: r, list, vector

I have a problem to append something into a list. 
I have 5 vectors as follow:

```
parent<-c("proc1", "proc2") 
child<-c("stor1")
proc1<-c("proc1L", "proc1H")
proc2<-c("proc2L", "proc2H")
stor1<-c("stor1L", "stor1H")
```

My question is, how can I produce combinatorial elements as shown below with expand.grid(), based on vector parent and child only:

```
    Var1   Var2   Var3
1 proc1L proc2L stor1L
2 proc1H proc2L stor1L
3 proc1L proc2H stor1L
4 proc1H proc2H stor1L
5 proc1L proc2L stor1H
6 proc1H proc2L stor1H
7 proc1L proc2H stor1H
8 proc1H proc2H stor1H
```

I tried to do something like this, but it doesnt work.

```
grid_vector<-list()
grid_vector<-append(grid_vector, parent)
grid_vector<-append(grid_vector, child)
expand.grid(grid_vector)
```

thank you for any suggestion

Comment: `expand.grid(proc1, proc2, stor1)` ?

Comment: thank @SymbolixAU... but the idea is to not use proc1,proc2,and stor1 directly.

Comment: found it 
 grid_vector<-append(grid_vector,list(get(paste(child[u],sep=""))))